# What is the purpose of configuring a remote?

Tags: git

On the [step 3 of the forking tutorial](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo) it is explained as follows:

> When a repository is cloned, it has a default remote called origin
>   that points to your fork on GitHub, not the original repository it was
>   forked from. To keep track of the original repository, you need to add
>   another remote named upstream:

Can you explain what is the purpose of doing that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The upstream remote should be configured so that you can get updates from the upstream (the original repo that you forked). Of course, if you're not interested in their updates, then you don't need this additional remote.

BTW, the name "upstream" is convention. You can use another name. But it's generally easier to follow conventions (they exist for precisely this purpose - facilitation).

### Update

Here a small illustration:

[image: fork upstream]

Unless you're tapping the upstream, all this mighty stream of fresh changes will bypass you and you'll likely dry out.